# Obtain variable value from a different widget

Tags: flutter, dart

What I want is when I click the switch button, the text in the `Option1Content` widget should change to true or false (depending upon the current value of the switch). The value is correct when you click the tile, select a different option from the drawer, and then come back to option 1, you will have the correct value. My requirement is when I press the switch tile the value of `Option1Content` should change instantly. For functionality reference: https://dartpad.dev/c9cabc35a0bda57758b1d1cf07f8a823. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  MyWidgetState createState()=> MyWidgetState();
}
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool status;
  Widget myBody;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  
   void closeDrawer() {
    if (_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
    }
  }
  
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    status = false;
    myBody = Option1Content(status:status);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key:_scaffoldKey,
    appBar:AppBar(
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      elevation:0,
      backgroundColor:Colors.transparent,
    actions:[
      Switch(
        inactiveThumbColor: Colors.black,
        activeColor: Colors.green,
        value:status,
        onChanged:(value){
          setState((){
            status=value;
          });
        })
    ]
    ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child:Center(child:ListView(children:[
          DrawerHeader(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 50,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 8.0, right: 8.0, top: 12.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'Account',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                              textScaleFactor: 1.3,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
          ListTile(title:Center(child:Text('Option 1')),onTap:(){
            closeDrawer();
            setState((){
              myBody = Option1Content(status:status);
            });
          }),
          ListTile(title:Center(child:Text('Option 2')),onTap:(){
            closeDrawer();
            setState((){
              myBody = Center(child:Text('Option 2 Content'));
            });
          }),
          ListTile(title:Center(child:Text('Option 3')),onTap:(){
            closeDrawer();
            setState((){
              myBody = Center(child:Text('Option 3 Content'));
            });
          }),
        ]))
      ),
      body: myBody
    );
  }
}



class Option1Content extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool status;
  Option1Content({@required this.status});

  @override
  _Option1ContentState createState() => _Option1ContentState();
}

class _Option1ContentState extends State<Option1Content> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('${widget.status}'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that simply changing the value of status doesn't update what is actually in `myBody`, which is what's shown. Even when changing `status` with `setState`, `myBody` still contains your widget with the old value of `status`.  This is why when you go to another `myBody` and come back, it's updated, because `myBody` now has the new widget with the updated `status` value.

To solve this you need to have a method of updating what's contained in `myBody`, because that's the only part that's being built. Doing the following is the simplest change.

Just change

```dart
setState((){
  status = value;
});
```

to

```dart
setState((){
  status = value;
  myBody = Option1Content(status:status);
});
```

and the full code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  MyWidgetState createState()=> MyWidgetState();
}
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool status;
  Widget myBody;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  
   void closeDrawer() {
    if (_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
    }
  }
  
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    status = false;
    myBody = Option1Content(status:status);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key:_scaffoldKey,
    appBar:AppBar(
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      elevation:0,
      backgroundColor:Colors.transparent,
    actions:[
      Switch(
        inactiveThumbColor: Colors.black,
        activeColor: Colors.green,
        value:status,
        onChanged:(value){
          setState((){
            status = value;
            myBody = Option1Content(status:status);
          });
        })
    ]
    ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child:Center(child:ListView(children:[
          DrawerHeader(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 50,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 8.0, right: 8.0, top: 12.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'Account',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                              textScaleFactor: 1.3,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
          ListTile(title:Center(child:Text('Option 1')),onTap:(){
            closeDrawer();
            setState((){
              myBody = Option1Content(status:status);
            });
          }),
          ListTile(title:Center(child:Text('Option 2')),onTap:(){
            closeDrawer();
            setState((){
              myBody = Center(child:Text('Option 2 Content'));
            });
          }),
          ListTile(title:Center(child:Text('Option 3')),onTap:(){
            closeDrawer();
            setState((){
              myBody = Center(child:Text('Option 3 Content'));
            });
          }),
        ]))
      ),
      body: myBody
    );
  }
}



class Option1Content extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool status;
  Option1Content({@required this.status});

  @override
  _Option1ContentState createState() => _Option1ContentState();
}

class _Option1ContentState extends State<Option1Content> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('${widget.status}'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. Any suggestions to handle this kind of scenario? I click one of the drawer element and the body is rebuilt?

Comment: @ritz This seems like a separate question. Please create a new question so you can provide more detail into your problem.